# why is defining an object variable outside of __init__ frowned upon?

Tags: python

I sometimes define an object variable outside of `__init__`. `plint` and my IDE (PyCharm) complain.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.nicevariable = 1   # everyone is happy

    def amethod(self):
        self.uglyvariable = 2   # everyone complains
```

`plint` output:

```
W:  6, 8: Attribute 'uglyvariable' defined outside __init__ (attribute-defined-outside-init)
```

Why is this a incorrect practice?

Comment: Related: [stackoverflow.com/q/19284857](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19284857)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Python allows you to add and delete attributes at any time.  There are two problems with not doing it at `__init__`

1. Your definitions aren't all in one place
2. If you use it in a function, you may not have defined it yet

Note that you can fix the above problem of setting an attribute later by defining it in `__init__` as:

```
self.dontknowyet = None      # Everyone is happy
```

Comment: So it's not unlike how JSLint/JSHint want you to move all your variable declarations to the beginning of their respective functions?

Comment: (1) relates to you and more important to everyone also trying to use your code. Be kind, make nice code and put definitions in one place

Comment: The important point being that it makes it much easier to reason about your code. Generally when we think of objects, we thing of a thing with a given set of attributes on it. Having to remember the circumstances under which some of those attributes appear leads to more potential bugs and a harder thing to work with.

Comment: I don't think that "Everyone is happy" by setting the attribute as None in the constructor. For example, consider you create a method for a database connection by Psycopg2: `self.cnx = psycopg2.connect(parameters)` then you write `self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()` and later you want to close this connection and you create a function for closing the connection where you write: `self.cursor.close()` and `self.cnx.close()`. Mypy then complains about: `Mypy: Item "None" of "Optional[Any]" has no attribute "close"  [union-attr]`. I agree this is better than not setting it to None in ___init__ though

Comment: In order to avoid my above-mentioned problem, you should check for None, i.e.: `if self.cursor is not None and self.cnx is not None:`. That's the last piece of the puzzle here. Also when it is possible, you should always set your variable in the constructor, i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame(), my_list = []` ... to provide further type safety and readability.

Comment: @Banik what if the variable's type is abstract class?