# When is it acceptable to declare an instance attribute outside "__init__()"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conventions, design-guidelines

I will start by describing the dilemma I'm currently facing. I've a class (let's call it `NeatClass`). It has several instance attributes, all of which I declare, as usual, within the class' `__init__()` method. I'm adding a new method (let's call it `util_method()`) to the class and it requires an internal state to be kept between calls. My intention is to store that state in an instance attribute (let's call it `self._util_attr`).

Now, according to the "usual guidelines", I should declare `self._util_attr` inside `NeatClass.__init__()`:

```
class NeatClass:
    def __init__():
        self.attr1 = ...
        self.attr2 = ...
        # ...
        self._util_attr = None  # type: ignore
```

I understand that declaring instance attributes inside `__init__()` is supposed to increase the code's readability (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284857/instance-attribute-attribute-name-defined-outside-init) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158898/why-is-defining-an-object-variable-outside-of-init-frowned-upon/25159060) SO questions) - I totally agree with it. However, in my use-case, doing so might have the opposite effect. Here's why:

- In my class, only `util_method()` is supposed to use `self._util_attr`.
- Although I want `util_method` to be part of my class' API, it will only be used in some rare occasions (most instances of `NeatClass` won't use this method at all).
- I'm using `mypy` to type-hint my code. During the call to `NeatClass.__init__()`, the type of `self._util_attr` isn't known (hence the comment `# type: ignore`). For reasons that are outside the scope of this question, I can't use `Union` or something like that to type-hint this variable.

So, what I really want to be doing is this:

```
class NeatClass:
    def __init__():
        self.attr1 = ...
        self.attr2 = ...
        # ...

    def util_method(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_util_attr"):
            self._util_attr = ...  # initial value of the variable
        # ...
```

However, I want my code to follow both [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html). So, I searched both guidelines for references to situations in which declaring an instance attribute outside `__init__()` is acceptable. As you might have imagined, I didn't find anything. As a matter of fact, I didn't find anything about "declaring instance attributes inside `__init__()`" at all, which really came as a surprise. This lead us to my question:

**Are there any situations in Python's common style guidelines (especially PEP8 and Google's) in which it is acceptable to declare instance attributes outside `__init__()__`?**

Pointers to where, in those guidelines, it's specified that instance attributes should only be declared inside `__init__()` would also be appreciated. Also, suggestions on how to refactor my code are welcome.

Please note that I'm not looking for opinions (which, in turn, would violate StackOverflow's guideline). I'm simply looking for references to sections of Python's most common style guidelines that address the situation I described. I also don't think this question is a duplicate - I've read several other SO's questions on the subject and none of them seemed to be asking the same thing I'm asking here.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: "only `util_method()` is supposed to use `self.util_attr`" Then `util_attr` should probably be a local variable

Comment: I assume ``util_attr`` should actually be ``_util_attr``, i.e. non-public? Is ``util_attr`` some sort of cache?

Comment: @DeepSpace Thank you for your response! As I pointed out in the question, I must be able to keep an internal state between calls to `util_method`, so it can't be a local variable. If I were using C, that would be a use-case for a `static` variable, I guess

Comment: In that case, you can make it a class attribute, which is Python's "version" of static variables. I'm not sure how nicely mypy plays with class attributes, but you should give it a go

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You're absolutely right! Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited the question

Comment: @DeepSpace That's an interesting idea! I will give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: Probably not a duplicate because you're using a class, but - [What is the Python equivalent of static variables inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function)

Comment: @DeepSpace Using a class attribute isn't an option either, since each instance of `NeatClass` must have its own cache/internal state (`self._util_attr`), possibly with very different values. I guess it wouldn't be a use-case, as I previously thought, for static variables either, if I were programming in C. Sorry about not realizing this before

Comment: @DeepSpace a static variable in C isn't really like a class attribute in Python (or like static attributes in other OO languages)

Comment: Anyway, what's wrong with setting it to some default value and type hinting it with `Any` ?