# Most Pythonic way of initializing instance variables

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently on some heavy data analytics projects, and am trying to create a Python wrapper class to help streamline a lot of the mundane preprocessing steps involved when cleaning data, partitioning it into test / validation sets, standardizing it, etc. The idea ultimately is to transform raw data into easily consumable processed matrices for machine learning algorithms to input for training and testing purposes. Ideally, I'm working towards the point where

```
data = DataModel(AbstractDataModel)
processed_data = data.execute_pipeline(**kwargs)
```

So in many cases I'll start off with a `self.df`, which is a `pandas` dataframe object for my instance. But one method may be called `standardize_data()` and will ultimately return a standardized dataframe called `self.std_df`.

My IDE has been complaining heavily about me initializing variables outside of `__init__`. So to try to soothe PyCharm, I've been using the following code inside my constructor:

```
class AbstractDataModel(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, input_path, ...,  **kwargs):

        self.df_train, self.df_test, self.train_ID, self.test_ID, self.primary_key, ... (many more variables) = None, None, None, None, None, ...
```

Later on, these properties are being initialized and set. I'll admit that I'm coming from heavy-duty Java Spring projects, so I'm still used to verbosely declaring variables. Is there a more Pythonic way of declaring my instance properties here? I know I must be violating DRY with all the `None` values.

I've researched on SO, and came across this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284857/instance-attribute-attribute-name-defined-outside-init), but the answer that is provided is more about setting instance variables through `argv`, so it isn't a direct solution in my context.

Comment: @Alexander I've attempted this solution. However, Pycharm complains that it needs more values to unpack, and at runtime, I get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` error.

Comment: @Alexander, that would result in an error (NoneType not iterable), maybe you meant `var1 = var2 = ... = varN = None`

Comment: My mistake, `self.var1 = self.var2 = ... = self.var_n = None`

Comment: As an aside, when you have lots of variables inside a class instance, you may want to alphabetize them and declare each individually.  I find that it helps me to maintain code.

Comment: @Alexander that's a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use chained assignment:

```
self.df_train = self.df_test = self.train_ID = self.test_ID = self.primary_key = ... = None
```

Or set up abstract properties that default to `None` (So you don't have to set them)

Comment: This is such a good idea, and so simple! Definitely Pythonic. Speaking of the abstract properties that default to `None`, could you clarify how that is different than what I'm doing in `__init__`? Since my constructor is an abstract method and all my properties are being set to `None` within this method?

Comment: `None` holds its own location in memory (`id(None)`).  Anything that has a value equal to `None` will point to this memory location.  Both methods are equivalent in their functionality, although one is much simpler.

Comment: Got it. So ```self.df_train is self.df_test``` will evaluate to true until I assign it values.