# in a class, how can I call a method onto an object that already has a class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, methods

I'm working with tkinter at the moment, ive needed to call a method onto an object that has a **Tk()** class. im trying to call the method not in the **Tk()** class, but from the class ive already created, which the tkinter object is in already.

Ive tried to call **.Format()** onto **l_label**, but i think it is trying to find an attribute or method within the **Label** class from tkinter, because it returns: *AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'Format'*

Any thoughts?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

thing = Tk()

class App():
    def __init__(self, master, _title, back='white'):
        self.master = master
        self._title = _title
        self.back = back
        self.master.title(self._title)
        self.master.configure(background=back)

    def label(self, _text, back='white', w=1, h=1):
        self.back = back
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self._text = _text
        l_label = Label(self.master, text=self._text, bg=self.back, width=self.w, height=self.h)
        return l_label

    def Format(self, l_label, Row=1, Column=1):
        self.Row = Row
        self.Column = Column
        l_label.grid(row=Row, column=Column)
        
app = App(thing, 'hello world')
label = app.label('this is a text boc', 'white').Format()
thing.mainloop()
```

Comment: pls indent the class

Comment: You have defined `Format` as a method of `App` objects, but it would accept a `Label` as its first parameter.  So you'd call it as `app.Format(label)`, or perhaps `app.Format(app.label(...))` if you didn't need the `label` variable for later.

Comment: True, that works. i suppose it was more of to get around to method chaining. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is method chaining. In order for that to work your function needs to return `self`

```
class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, _title, back='white'):
        self.master = master
        self._title = _title
        self.back = back
        self.master.title(self._title)
        self.master.configure(background=back)
        self.w = None
        self.h = None
        self._text = None
        self.Row = None
        self.Column = None
        self.l_label = None

    def label(self, _text, back='white', w=1, h=1):
        self.back = back
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self._text = _text
        self.l_label = Label(self.master, text=_text, bg=back, width=w, height=h)
        return self

    def Format(self, Row=1, Column=1):
        self.Row = Row
        self.Column = Column
        self.l_label.grid(row=Row, column=Column)
        return self
```

Notice how I removed the `l_label` from Format and assigned `Label(self.master, text=_text, bg=back, width=w, height=h)` to `self.l_label`

Then you would be able to do:

```
thing = Tk()
app = App(thing, 'hello world')
label = app.label('this is a text box', 'white', 15, 15).Format()
thing.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was just what i was looking for :). Is there any reason for all of the self variables to be listed in the __init__ with None value? Or is it to just for the script to be more organised?

Comment: It is so you do not define an instance attribute outside of `__init__` Here is a quick answer as to why we assign it to None in `__init__`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19292653/9177877

Comment: Actually `app` and `label` are referring the same instance of `App` class, so `label` is not necessary.

Comment: thats true acw1668, im not sure why i did that