# Inside class, can i call other methods variable inside another method?

Tags: python, class, methods, init

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=10


        
    def bvalue(self):
        self.b=20
         
    def add1(self):
        c=self.a+self.b
        print(c)
        
a1=A()
a1.add1()

ouput
 AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Im decalring a=10 inside **init** mehthod and declaring b=20 inside another method, and using 3rd method im trying to add a+b. but why it's giving error?
am i making any mistakes here?

Comment: Attributes belong to objects, not functions.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19284857/9958281

Answer (score 0):

you should call method  bvalue first before you call  add1

try:

```
a1=A()
a1.bvalue()
a1.add1()
```

Comment: yes bro, now its working, Thank you so much for your help